# Alternatives to tempfile.mkdtemp

Tags: python

To create and declare a temp file all the the same time I am currently using:

```
import tempfile
myTempFile=tempfile.mkdtemp()+'/script.txt'
```

While this approach works... I wonder if there are other ways to do it. What I don't like with the current setup is that:

1. It seems it takes some time to import `tempfile` module.
2. The directory `tempfile.mkdtemp()` creates a way too deep. On my mac it looks like:

   ```
   /var/folders/35/xxrdb2zs7s16grb4pyd0llm00000gp/T/tmpEYRGFO/s/script.txt
   ```
3. I have to specify the name of the file my summing the args with :

   ```
   tempfile.mkdtemp()+'/script.txt'
   ```

Comment: *It seems it takes some time to import tempfile module.* **Hardly**. *The directory `tempfile.mkdtemp()` creates a way too deep* That is the platform default for Mac, why is that a problem?

Comment: As for `3`, use `os.path.join()`, or better yet, use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` then.

Comment: No problem. I just wonder if there are other ways to do the same job. What if others find there is a simpler, with more fun of doing it. I have been using tempfile module for a while. I thought it would be a good time to check on Stackoverflow if I am not making a mistake by sticking to the same module when everyone else had already switched the gears....

Comment: What do you need to use the temporary files *for*; what is their expected lifecycle? Do they need to live on beyond the Python script lifetime? Do you need access to a temporary file object from just your script, or is there a requirement for another process to access the same file? There are too many unknowns here. `tempfile` is the proper module to use in all usecases that I can think of, in any case.

Comment: As soon as Python code exits there is no need in a temp file created.

Comment: Then use `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` if you don't need a name (it'll be unlinked *immediately* so there is no directory entry and the OS will reap it the moment the file handle is closed) or use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` if a name *is* needed (it'll be closed and unlinked automatically when the object is cleaned up when the reference count drops to 0 at the latest).

Comment: The `tempfile` module's documentation provides several alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

If another another wants to use the temporary file created by another user, it would not be possible. So, if ur use case demands switching to a different user, this is not the library to go to